# Installing a RoR stack with chef

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, vagrant

I am trying to install a RoR stack, at the moment I don't really care which Application server  is used.

I want to use chef-solo & vagrant (development) or ec2(production) and can't find a good walkthrough or tutorial to help me get started without needing to spend days learning chef.

I couldn't find anything that fits those requirements which seems a bit odd since this looks like a great combo for any RoR developer.

Comment: So you want to manage your application with chef, but don't want to learn chef? I think I see the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the application_ruby cookbook https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application_ruby  Beyond that, the chef docs are quite good (as are the vagrant docs) and you should be able to sort out a simple deploy relatively quickly with those

Comment: Have you figured out a way to get `application` cookbooks to use a Vagrant shared directory for local deploys?